# Property delegate must have a 'getValue(ChatActivity, KProperty<*>)' method. None of the following functions is suitable:

Tags: android, kotlin

```
//getting an error in android studio when using lazy for getStringExtra

private val name : String by lazy {
    intent.getStringExtra(UID)
}
```

another class

[image]

```
 val intent = Intent(requireContext(),ChatActivity::class.java)
                      intent.putExtra(UID,id)
                      intent.putExtra(NAME,name)
                      intent.putExtra(IMAGE,photo)
                      startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 8):

In `Kotlin`, you cannot assign `Nullable` types to `Non-Nullable`, `getStringExtra` returns `String?` which is not compatible with `String`

Try below

```
private val name : String? by lazy {
    intent.getStringExtra(UID)
}
```

or

```
private val name : String by lazy {
    intent.getStringExtra(UID)?:""
}
```

Comment: This is such a simple mistake to make. The error message could be a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just need to invalidate cashes and build the project again. Especially if errors have no logic and were not existed before. In my case, I face it when work with git's branches.